# Как вывести из списка все элементы отвечающие условию и при этом проверить список на null совпадение?

Tags: android, kotlin

Как вывести из списка все элементы отвечающие условию и чтобы не было ошибки если в списке нет элемента, отвечающего условию?
Например такой код проверяет список на null, но выводит только первый элемент.

```
fun main() {
    val ListOfNames = listOf("Tom", "Lu", "Sam")
    val NameOfUser = ListOfNames.firstOrNull{ name-> name.length > 2}
    println(NameOfUser)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    val listOfNames = listOf("Tom", "Lu", "Sam", null)
    val nameOfUser = listOfNames.filter { name -> name != null && name.length > 2 }
    println(nameOfUser)
}
```